# Is there any way to disable QListWidgetItem in my QListWidget?

Tags: qt, select, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I am using `QListWidgetItem` to add Items in my `QListWidget`.

In some situations, I want some rows of my `QListWidget` become **non selectable**. (I mean I want some `QListWidgetItem` to be **non selectable**)

Is ther any way to do this?

PS: I tried

```
listWidgetItem->setFlags(Qt::NoItemFlags)

listWidgetItem->setSelected(false);
```

but they don't disable the selection of items.

Edit:

```
QStringList _strListClients = _strClients.split(",",QString::KeepEmptyParts,Qt::CaseInsensitive);

for(int i = 0; i < _strListClients.count(); i++)//Add Client's Check Boxes
{
    QListWidgetItem* _listWidgetItem = new QListWidgetItem(_strListClients[i], listWidgetClients);
    listWidgetClients->addItem(_listWidgetItem);

    if(_strListClients[i] == "Unknown"){
        _listWidgetItem->setSelected(false);
        _listWidgetItem->setTextColor(Qt::red);
        _listWidgetItem->setFlags(_listWidgetItem->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsSelectable);

    }
```

}

Comment: But you're not removing the selectable flag as I said in my answer...

Comment: I did. but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the [`Qt::ItemIsSelectable` flag](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum)  from each item:

```
item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
```

Or remove `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` if you want to remove *all* interaction with the item.

E.g.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QListWidget widget;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(QStringLiteral("Item %1").arg(i));
        if (i % 2 == 0) // disable one every two
            item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
        widget.addItem(item);
    }

    widget.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: parden? what do U mean by "SSSCE"?

Comment: Can you please paste a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: 'QStringList _strList = _str.split(",",QString::KeepEmptyParts,Qt::CaseInsensitive);

    for(int i = 0; i < _strList.count(); i++)//Add Client's Check Boxes
    {
        QListWidgetItem* _listWidgetItem = new QListWidgetItem(_strList[i], listWidget);
        listWidget->addItem(_listWidgetItem);

        if(_strList[i] == "Unknown"){
            _listWidgetItem->setSelected(false);
            _listWidgetItem->setTextColor(Qt::red);
        }
    }'

Comment: Please edit your original post and add the code in there :) It's ... difficult to understand it in here, written like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1) Override the clicked/selection event (sorry I don't remember the exact name.
Doing so you  can have some sort of flag/bool value on the item, and if is set as not being selectable you just return.

2) Rather then override you just connect to the signal and perform the above check and if you don't want to select that item you un-select it afterwards.

A bit of a work around but I don't know if there is a built in way to do so.
Checking the documentation I did not see a disable method on the item itself.

If you go down the road of list view you should have more control on that, also on the display, so you might be able to displayed it greyed etc. A view is a bit more work though.

M.

Comment: I used " connect(listWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(itemIsSelected(QListWidgetItem*))); " for another reason. when the items are selectable. I wanted to desect some of them for another reason

Comment: you should be able to handle the extra complexity in the same function